# Trying to automate Amazon login using Selenium but getting JavaScript error

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate Amazon login using Selenium but getting a JavaScript error. The following code gives the error below, how to solve this?

```js
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
action = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(1)

driver.get('http://www.amazon.in')
time.sleep(3)

firstLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-link-accountList"]/span[2]')
 driver.implicitly_wait(3)
 action.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform()
 time.sleep(3)
```

Getting error at `"action.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform()"`

> ```
> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message:
> javascript error: Failed to execute  'elementsFromPoint' on
> 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite. (Session info:
> chrome=86.0.4240.75)**
> ```

Comment: waiting for an element is in every case better than a sleep. sleeps are evil, don't so sleeps :) see @arundeep-chocan's response

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to open that account tab.

```
driver.get('http://www.amazon.in')
try:
    firstLevelMenu =WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#nav-link-accountList")))
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform()
except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```